# How can I get the data I need from this XML block using C# and linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this XML Data that I am trying to put into a list of C# classes using linq.

```
<Competency name="GRAPHICAL USER INTERFACE">
    <CompetencyId id="7310031" /> 
    <TaxonomyId id="731" idOwner="10" description="Sovren" /> 
    <CompetencyEvidence name="GRAPHICAL USER INTERFACE" typeDescription="Found in SKILLS; WORK HISTORY; POS-2; POS-3; POS-4; POS-5; POS-6" typeId="7310031" lastUsed="2010-01-01">
        <NumericValue description="Total Months">204</NumericValue>
    </CompetencyEvidence>
</Competency>
```

My code is as follows. I try to grab the values, grab the distinct values and then populate them into a list. Where am I going wrong?

```
    var skills = from competency in xmlData.Descendants(ns + "CompetencyEvidence")
        select new 
        {
            Name = competency.Attribute("name").Value,
            Months = from p in xmlData.Descendants(ns + "NumericValue")
                select new SkillDataContract()
                {
                    Months = p.Attribute("description").Value
                }
        };

        //Get DISTINCT
        var distinctSkills = skills.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(y => y.First());


        var processedSkills = distinctSkills.Select(item => new SkillDataContract()
        {
            Name = item.Name,
            Months = item.Months.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Have you debugged your code? That should give you enough information to solve the issue.

Comment: Is that your entire xml document? I don't see any namespaces, why are you namespacing?

Comment: what is it that is wrong? error message? no output? compilation error?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.  As it stands, in order to answer your question we need to know 1) the content of the variable `ns`; 2) The XML all the way up to and including the root element.  Otherwise, we're just guessing your problem.